# Functions Save() and SaveAs() are too slow

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I'm trying to convert from Json to Excel. The json is huge. So, i can't use a directly convert.

I'm talking about 12 millions of entries at least.

I'm reading Json file with JsonReader and converting part by part to DataTable.

ExcelSheet has 1048576 rows limit. So, I need to create differents sheets.

So, i'm loading differents sheets from DataTables. The problem is when all my DataTables are loaded, the Save() operation never ends.

A little snippet:

```
private void LoadDataTable(DataTable dt, ExcelPackage ep, string newName){
       OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet sheet = ep.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(newName); 
       sheet.Cells.LoadFromDataTable(dt, true);
}



static void Main(string[] args)
{
         using (ExcelPackage ep = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(output)))
         using (StreamReader sw = new StreamReader(input))
         using (JsonTextReader jr = new JsonTextReader(sw))
         {

               while(jr.Read()){
                   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                       .........

                   //Filling DataTable with data.
                       .........
                   LoadDataTable(dt,ep,"foo"+i);

               } //The total of the the iterations takes 6 minutes more or less

               ep.Save();// Never ends. Here is my problem. 
         }
}
```

i think the operation `sheet.Cells.LoadFromDataTable(dt, true);` load all the data in memory but not in a file. When `ep.Save()`runs, it starts a dump from memory to a file. so, it is extremaly ineficient.

Is any way to write directly in a excel file? or how can i do `ep.Save()` faster?

UPDATE:

I found this[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47822689/very-slow-operation-of-epplus-save-saveas-etc-methods-when-debugging).

I'm using .NET Core and the Epplus version is v4.5.3.2

Comment: You know XLSX is a compressed format? So you can't just open a file and write a memory block, you have to read it entirely, decompress, edit, compress and save.

Comment: i didn't know it. So, i have to find the way to use `ep.Save()` faster. I don't know why is slow.

Comment: I don't know your reasons for focussing on excel, but if you have a row count that clearly exceeds the excel format limit, then my first thought is, that you try to use the wrong tool (format) for the job. Noone ever wants to open such a bloated excel file anyway and a machine can work with other formats.

Comment: Writing to csv will be faster, though not sure if I'd want to open that large a CSV in Excel

Comment: @Maverick94: it's slow because that is a quite a large load of data, and Excel files are not a plain text files like CSV that you can append in chunks.

Comment: Where does the JSON come from? It sounds like you're serving as a man in the middle between some data analytics guys and a data repository. In this case, I'd just try and argue that your role itself is redundant; just let them do analytics against the source data repository itself.

Comment: @chill94 it's a conversor from json to excel. This conversor should be able to convert everything. This conversion has no sense but it has to be able to do it.

Comment: A converter should have limits. If you say that your converter should be able to handle *everything*, even when it doesn't fit into the target structure (row limit per sheet), then I can always throw some amount of data at you, where you fail due to physical constraints (first, your accessible RAM will be to small, then followup-problems will occur). Now you are at the point where a premade library fails. You can start writing the XML and packing the xlsx file yourself - worth the efford?

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, having Excel workbooks of 12 millions records has to be discouraged.
How do you think users can work with so huge amount of data ?

This is very bad design.

You should rather use a database to import and store all that stuff and then implement SQL queries which result can be integrated in smaller excel files.

Comment: Maverick94 - Whoever told you to copy the data to excel for backup/archive/transport/import/etl/whateverreason, tell them instead that there are other file/db formats for that purpose. If that's for "researcher" or "analysts" so they can import and analyze data, then get them to learn that their tools can import data right from databases as well, not just from excel or csv files..

Comment: it's a conversor from json to excel. This conversor should be able to convert everything. This conversion has no sense but it has to be able to do it

Answer (score 2):

If you MUST use excel in this case (wholly cow thats going to be a big file!) I strongly advise you to avoid using any of the `LoadFrom*()` methods built into EPPlus and write your own loops.  Those methods are handy but come at a major performance cost since they have to account for ALL conditions and not just yours.  I have shaved off not seconds but **minutes** in exports simply by writing my own for/while loops.

As far as improving `SaveAs()` you are at the mercy of the library at that point.  I have had much smaller data sets take as much as 10-15 minutes to generate the XLSX (dont ask :o).  About the only way to improve that would be to generate the raw XML that is saved in the XLSX zip file itself to bypass all of the library logic because, again, it has to account for ALL possibilities.  But this is no small feat - alot has to go into mapping the cells and files in the zip property which is why I never put the time into figuring it out.

Comment: i thought about it (generate the raw XML) but i think it's very hard.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've already argued with your team that Excel is not a database tool, and for some reason have been told that it's not up for discussion -

There's a couple things you could try here:

- Load the data into several separate excel files after doing some experimentation regarding how much data can be efficiently saved into a single file. This is different from using separate sheets in the sense that you can clear out memory between saves. Plus, whoever is loading this already will need some wonky reader that looks through different Excel sheets; it wouldn't be difficult to modify that to read through different files instead.
- Save the data as a .csv file, and then convert it to an Excel format later (or not at all!). The limitation here is that you again cannot use Excel sheets, so you'd end up having to (getting to) take Excel out of the equation all together, or once again save as many different Excel files.